# Using Index & Small function to get multiple values from other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have 2 sheets and I want to get revenue for new user and old user in sheet2. I tried below formula but no success so far. I am new to excel please help me

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!E3:E8,LARGE(IF(A3&B3=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7&Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7,ROW(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$7)-ROW(Sheet1!E2)),1))
```

[image: Sheet2]

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Error after using SUMIFS function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a sumif would be the easiest way to achieve what I understand you want:

in D2

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$E:$E,Sheet1!$B:$B,"="&$B2,Sheet1!$A:$A,"="&$A2,Sheet1!$F:$F,"new")
```

in E2

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$E:$E,Sheet1!$B:$B,"="&$B2,Sheet1!$A:$A,"="&$A2,Sheet1!$F:$F,"old")
```

This formula can be extended in all your cells from D2 to E4

Comment: But, this formula gives me total sum and I want separate values for both in different columns in sheet2.